# Accessible jQuery toggles odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm setting up a reusable jQuery toggle function (for my employer) to enable show/hide of content (eg FAQs), to improve accessibility over existing inline onClick bindings.

In JSFiddle everything is fast and fluid, but when I transfer to the preview server an odd behaviour becomes apparent. Clicking the button works as normal, but on clicking the button's link text there's a noticeable delay before anything happens.

Is there anything within the script that might be causing the delay? Or anything which is an obvious candidate for conflicts of some kind?

Anyway, here's the code (based on [Mike Raynham's accessible toggles](http://www.mikeraynham.co.uk/articles/accessible-jquery-toggles)):

http://jsfiddle.net/internet_man/9yKKM/2/

html:

```
<div class="buttons"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><strong class="_toggle type noscript">This is the first toggle</strong> 
            <ul class="_toggle-this show-hide"> 
                <li><a href="#"><strong>Option One</strong></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><strong>Option Two</strong></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><strong>Option Three</strong></a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li class="bad-break"><strong class="_toggle type noscript">This is the second toggle (a bit longer than the first)</strong> 
            <ul class="_toggle-this show-hide"> 
                <li><a href="#"><strong>Option One</strong></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><strong>Option Two</strong></a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li class="bad-break"><strong class="_toggle type noscript">This is the third toggle (also somewhat longer)</strong> 
            <ul class="_toggle-this show-hide"> 
                <li><a href="#"><strong>Option One</strong></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><strong>Option Two</strong></a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Script:

```
var create_name = function(text) {
    var name = text.toLowerCase();
    name = name.replace(/^\s+|\s+jQuery|[^a-z0-9&\s-]/g, ''); 
    name = name.replace(/&/g, 'and'); 
    name = name.replace(/\s/g, '-'); 
    name = name.replace(/(-)+\1/g, "jQuery1"); 
    return name; 
}; 

var add_link = function() {
    var name = create_name(jQuery(this).text()); 
    jQuery(this).next('.toggle-this').attr('name', name); 
    jQuery(this).html('<a href="#' + name + '" title="Show content">' + jQuery(this).html() + '</a>'); 
}; 
var toggle = function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('expanded').nextAll('.toggle-this').slideToggle(100);
    jQuery('.toggle-this').not(jQuery(this).siblings()).slideUp(100);
    jQuery('.toggle').not(jQuery(this)).removeClass('expanded'); 
}; 

var remove_focus = function() { 
    jQuery(this).blur(); 
}; 

jQuery(function (){ 
    jQuery('._toggle').removeClass('_toggle, noscript').addClass('toggle'); 
    jQuery('._toggle-this').removeClass('_toggle-this').addClass('toggle-this');
    jQuery('._expanded').removeClass('_expanded').addClass('expanded'); 
    jQuery('.toggle:not(.expanded)').nextAll('.toggle-this').hide(); 
    jQuery('.toggle').each(add_link); 
    jQuery('.toggle').click(toggle); 
    jQuery('.toggle a').mouseup(remove_focus); 
});
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    font-size:62.5%;
    color:#666;
    font-family:arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

a
{
    color:#462170;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}

strong
{
    font-weight:normal;
}

div.buttons
{
    width:462px;
    line-height:2.2em;
    margin:1.5em 0;
}

.buttons li > strong
{
    font-size:1.9em;
}

.toggle, .buttons .type.noscript
{
    display:block;
    font-size:1.9em;
    height:65px;
    background:url(http://oi48.tinypic.com/dy6xf.jpg) 0 -85px no-repeat;
    padding:20px 0 0 90px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#462170;
    cursor:pointer;
    cursor:hand;
}

.toggle a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}

.toggle strong
{
    display:block;
    height:65px;
    border:1px dotted red;
}

.toggle:hover, .toggle:focus
{
    background-position:0 0;
}

.buttons .show-hide 
{
    border-bottom:6px solid white;
}

.buttons .show-hide li      
{
    margin-left:12px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-top:2px solid white;
    font-size:1em;
}

.buttons .show-hide a       
{
    display:block;
    height:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#462170;
    background:#f1f1f1 url(http://oi46.tinypic.com/6iedtw.jpg) 5px 14px no-repeat;
    padding:12px 0 15px 58px;
}

.buttons .show-hide a:hover, .connection-buttons .show-hide a:focus 
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:black;
    background-color:#ece8f0;
    background-position:5px -41px;
}

li.bad-break a
{
    padding-right:30%;
}
```

Notes:

Scripts on -- ._toggle becomes .toggle, ._toggle-this becomes .toggle-this, .noscript is removed and a link is inserted around (in this case) the strong element of class toggle, pointing to the next '.toggle-this' element.

Scripts off -- No toggle created but it's styled as though the accordions are expanded.

Comment: Is it all enclosed within a function so you're not cluttering up the global namespace with things like `add_link`, `toggle`, etc? Also, it's unlikely to be something within this script, if it's working well isolated.

Comment: It is now :*) but still showing the same quirk unfortunately. With you on the second point -- I'd wondered whether on the live server everything was running slower (for some reason) and so showing up an issue that wasn't obvious on the faster server.

Comment: Just to close this one -- on transfer to live everything worked just as it should and no sign of weird bugs. Thanks again for all helps.